# NodeJS, MariaDB pool connection commit not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, promise, mariadb

I've searched already on the internet, but couldn't find a solution to my problem.
I'm using NodeJS and a MariaDB with a pool connection.
I get a connection from the pool, make a transaction (no errors) but I cannot see any chances inside my database.
If I use the query without a transaction, just with pool.query(...) then it works fine. I know for just one query I wouldn't need a transaction, but I have just simplified the code for you.

```
pool.getConnection()
.then(conn =>{
    conn.beginTransaction()
        .then(() =>{
            return conn.query("UPDATE Users SET forename='Tom' WHERE user_id=8")
        })
        .then(()=>{
            console.log("commit")
            conn.commit()
            //conn.end() --> doesn't change anything

        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err.message);
            conn.rollback()
    })
});
```

What's wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work without using a pool?

Comment: no, doesn't work either:/

Comment: only thing working was creating a new connection for the query, but this seems strange to me

Comment: I agree. I assume that nothing is being logged by MariaDB either? Perhaps this issue is relevant: https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-nodejs/issues/24#issuecomment-438080683 (so instead of `conn.commit()` you should try and use `conn.query('COMMIT')`). And FWIW, I think that you still need to call `conn.end()` when you're done with the transaction, to release the connection back to the pool.

Comment: using conn.query("commit") fixed it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in the MariaDB driver, where `conn.commit()` doesn't actually commit. The bug is documented [here](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-nodejs/issues/24#issuecomment-438080683).

In that comment, a workaround is suggested, by calling `COMMIT` manually:

```
conn.query('COMMIT');
```

Also make sure that you end the connection when you're done, to release the connection back into the pool:

```
.then(()=>{
  return conn.query("COMMIT").then(() => {
    return conn.end();
  });
})
.catch((err)=>{
  return conn.query("ROLLBACK").then(() => {
    conn.end();
    throw new Error(err)
  });
})
```

Comment: yes that worked:) Where should I close the connections? Is this right?

Comment: does it also work like I did? Or is it neccessary to return conn.end()?

Comment: @mcAngular2 it _may_ work with your solution, but it would depend on how the MariaDB library is implemented. The reason why I use `return conn.*` is that that will cause the promises that are returned by each operation to be resolved _before_ the next `.then` is executed, whereas using `conn.query(...); conn.end()` doesn't do that.

Comment: but how can I then know whether the connection was closed because of conn.rollback or conn.commit? I need to know whether everything worked or not

Comment: Ohh okay, if you want to re-throw the error, you can use something similar to your code. See edit.

Comment: btw, this is https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJS-52, and will be corrected in next release (in a day)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, and as @robertklep indicate, a workaround is to execute a conn.query("COMMIT") command.

But is [jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJS-52](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJS-52), and is now corrected with the latest release (2.0.1)